# Getting black screenshot by using android screenshot library

Tags: android, screenshot

I'm using the Android Screenshot Library (ASL) trying to capture screenshots.
Currently I'm running ASL in asl-native, included in ASL 1.2.

When I press the "get screenshot"-button in my app it's telling me that the screen is successfully captured, but when I check the gallery all that it has captured is a black screen.

I've downloaded the Android Screenshot Library from [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/downloads/list)

Does anyone know what might be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Are you by any chance trying to capture the screen from an emulator ? If so, make sure "use host GPU" is off (or override it by appending "gpu off" when launching the emulator via command line).

When using GPU acceleration on the emulator host all screenshots taken will result in a black image.